# How to run Openscad from windows command prompt

Tags: python, subprocess, call, command-prompt, openscad

I am trying to run OpenScad through command prompt in windows 7. However I could not get it worked.
I added following directory to Path

```
"C:\Program Files\OpenSCAD\"
```

And tried to run the following script:

```
from os import listdir
from subprocess import call

files = listdir('.')
for f in files:
    if f.find(".scad") >= 0:            # get all .scad files in directory
        of = f.replace('.scad', '.stl') # name of the outfile .stl
        cmd = 'call (["openscad.com",  "-o", "{}",  "{}"])'.format(of, f)   #create openscad command
        exec(cmd)
```

Also I tried it with openscad, openscad.exe, openscad.com, no success so far. 
The error I am getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\scad2stl.py", line 9, in <module>
    exec(cmd)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\subprocess.py", line 247, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\subprocess.py", line 676, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\subprocess.py", line 955, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The specified file could not be found
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: the error means path to openscad.exe was not found. please look, if path to openscad.exe is really in Path. I can run the code on windows 7 and 10 if the Path is set properly. on python 3.5 and higher `subprocess.call()` can be replaced by `subprocess.run()`, see the edit of my previous answer

Answer (score 0):

I just saw this thread, I have make it work usign windows power shell, couldn't make it work on cmd due. So for example this doesn't work on cmd>

> > openscad -o render.png  --imgsize=2048,2048 assembly.scad

but it does work on power shell (notice the ./ in the bigining):

> > ./openscad -o render.png  --imgsize=2048,2048 assembly.scad

hope it helps.
Best regards

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Notepad.
2. Paste the following text:

> ```
> @echo off
> "C:\Program Files\OpenSCAD\openscad.com" %*
> ```

3. Save the file as openscad.bat in a directory included in your PATH
   environment variable (e.g., C:\Windows\System32).
4. Close and reopen the Command Prompt to apply changes.
5. Use the openscad command as desired.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).